# Getting a certain digit from decimal in C

Tags: c

I have `int x = 346`.

I need to get in turn, each time a new digit of it, so first 3, then 4, then 6.
Using `floor` does not help me here,
and other examples here give only the left/right digit.

Is there a simple algorithm?

Comment: modulus 10, modulus 100...

Comment: Yes, use integer division and modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a%10` gives you the last digit of a number i.e. its remainder when divided by 10. You can print all the digits of a number like so:

```
void print_digits(int a) {
  while (a > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", a%10);
    a /= 10;
  }
}
```

This will print the digits from least significant to most significant. You can get them in reverse order if you use an auxiliary stack for instance.

Comment: Of course, you won't want to call this function with a negative number.

Comment: Yes i will put the limits to it . thanks. i can accept that in 9 minutes .